# Ionic Load More scrolling slow

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

Hi I am new to Ionic and,
I am using AngularJS with Ionic v1 here **load more scrolling** is too much slowed.
I have tried two ways

1. Service
2. Factory

   both ways are very slow. how can I speed up my load more option.

These are the values  i am getting from the api REST service

```
{
    "shared_status": "false",
    "wall_post_id": "740",
    "post_post": "getU.online",
    "post_added_by": "589",
    "post_company_name": "The Business Club",
    "post_business_sector": null,
    "post_busin_type": "Limited Company",
    "post_added_by_image": "1471523735.png",
    "post_added_by_name": "Russ Wheeler",
    "post_added_on": "14 hours ago",
    "post_date": "2017-01-31 18:48:36",
    "post_mine": true,
    "image_list": [{
        "file_name": "http:\/\/www.domain.com\/uploads\/wall_posts\/tmp\/\/1485888514.jpg"
    }],
    "like_status": "activated",
    "like_test": false,
    "like_test_1": "Unlike",
    "like": " Like",
    "num_like": "1",
    "no_of_reply": 1,
    "comment": "comment"
}
```

Comment: Could you give more details, are you using ion-infinite-scroll directive, is it slow itself ? did you check the data you're loading in the request, maybe it is too big so it takes time to load ?

Comment: so you have an image in the response which makes the request load slow, try to compress the image size for better performance and check your connection speed.

Comment: I am compressing the images while uploading Images are fine but app very slow. is there any other method to speed up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use only ionic directive wherever possible as they are designed keeping mobile performance in mind. Using non-ionic directives will but, at the cost of performance.

So, if you are using some custom / plugin based solution .. remove that and instead use `<ion-infinite-scroll>`

Here is sample :

```
<ion-infinite-scroll
  ng-if="moreDataCanBeLoaded()"
  icon="ion-loading-c"
  on-infinite="loadMoreData()">
</ion-infinite-scroll>
```

> Read more :
>   https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionInfiniteScroll/

Comment: Yeah bro I am using <ion-infinite-scroll> but very slow it's taking 4 - 10 Sec to show a data. How can i speed up

Answer (score 0):

First Check your API calls latency. If they are okey then use followings
to increase ionic app performance loading list and etc.
Try to do following things.

- Add  [crosswalk plugin](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview) (This will increase your .apk file size but performance wise it will be good option )
- If you can use [one time data-binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)(::) in your list item use it
- Use track by in you ng-repeat list item (eg. ng-repeat="item in items track by item.id" or ng-repeat="item in items track by $index")
- When application in production remove console.log if have any

Also you can find out some more performance tips in this [link](https://julienrenaux.fr/2015/08/24/ultimate-angularjs-and-ionic-performance-cheat-sheet/)